# Spring Cloud GCP with Cloud SQL - Autoconfig attempts connection to wrong Cloud SQL Instance

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I had a previous GCP project - let's call it `delicate-flower-112233` that was connecting successfully to a cloud SQL instance, and then I deleted that project and wanted to start fresh.  I'm not building anything for production use yet, as I'm still learning the ins and outs of GCP.  I am using the following frameworks/dependencies:

```
com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:2.0.5:pom:import
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.5:pom:import
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.delicate.flower.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>delicate-flower-data-svc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>delicate-flower-data-svc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>2.0.4</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.5.5</spring-boot.version>
        <gcp-project.id>delicate-flower-112233</gcp-project.id>
        <gcp-artifact-repository.name>mvn-artifacts</gcp-artifact-repository.name>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>artifact-registry</id>
            <url>>artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/${gcp-project.id}/${gcp-artifact-repository.name}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>artifact-registry</id>
            <url>>artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/${gcp-project.id}/${gcp-artifact-repository.name}</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>artifact-registry</id>
            <url>>artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/${gcp-project.id}/${gcp-artifact-repository.name}</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.delicate.flower.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-delicate-flower-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.artifactregistry</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactregistry-maven-wagon</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

</project>
```

After deleting that project, I created a new GCP project.  Let's call this one `millenial-snowflake-696969`.  For all intents and purposes, it has the same pom.xml, the same dependencies, and the same overall code structure.  Just the GCP project itself is different, with a new Cloud SQL (postgresql) instance.  I can connect to the Cloud SQL instance from my home desktop using `cloud_sql_proxy` just fine.

However, when I attempt to run the application, a weird error occurs.

Here is my application.properties:

```
#name the application
spring.application.name=millenial-snowflake-data-svc

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=${sm://projects/3216549871321/secrets/postgres-user/versions/1}

spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=cloudsql-db-name
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=millenial-snowflake-696969:us-central1:cloud-sql-instancename

spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=millenial-snowflake-696969

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Aaaaaand here is the error I'm seeing:

```json
java.lang.RuntimeException: [millenial-snowflake-696969:us-central1:cloud-sql-instancename] Failed to update metadata for Cloud SQL instance.
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.addExceptionContext(CloudSqlInstance.java:624) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.fetchMetadata(CloudSqlInstance.java:505) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131) ~[guava-31.0.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74) ~[guava-31.0.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82) ~[guava-31.0.1-jre.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
GET https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/millenial-snowflake-696969/instances/us-central1~gcp-poc
{
  "code": 403,
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "USER_PROJECT_DENIED"
    }
  ],
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Project delicate-flower-112233 has been deleted.",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Project delicate-flower-112233 has been deleted.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I'm thinking there is a cached Oauth2 token somewhere on my machine, or in my core GCP configuration, but can't find it and don't really know where to look.  I also ran the application in debug mode to see if I could gain any insight.  There were a couple of hints about missing beans of type `GcpEnvironmentProvider` and `GcpProjectIdProvider` so I added those to my Config class to see if I could override anything.  No joy.  Same error.

Has anyone ever seen this, or know what's going on?  I'm stumped.

Comment: As you mentioned that you are currently working in a new GCP Project ensure that all the APIs that your application is using are currently [enabled](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api#enabling_the_api).

Use the `gcloud services list` command in your cloud Shell to list all enabled APIs and ensure that 

```NAME: sqladmin.googleapis.com
TITLE: Cloud SQL Admin API``` 

is in there

Comment: I had ensured that already, and all the necessary APIs are enabled.

Comment: As an update, the application -- when deployed in GCP -- works just fine with no problems.  This further leads me to believe there is something locally on my machine that is erroneously still trying to connect to the old GCP Project instance instead of the new one.